# GroupBy object in which entries can belong to several groups

Tags: python, pandas

By the methods it supports, it looks like nothing speaks against labels of the original data frame/series occuring multiple times in a derived `GroupBy` object. Is it actually possible to, for example, construct a GroupBy object `g` from an iterable column like `a` in

```
>>> x
       a b
0 [0, 1] 1
1 [1, 2] 2
```

such that `g` will represent a GroupBy object with one entry for each of the entries in `a`'s values? That is, I get results like

```
>>> x.iterable_groupby('a').size()
a
0 1
1 2
2 1
>>> x.iterable_groupby('a').mean()
    b
0 1.0
1 1.5
2 2.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should reshape your DataFrame to a tidy dataset. Reshaping part is asked frequently ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078282/normalizing-data-by-duplication)).

In a tidy dataset, each row should represent a single record. For that, you can create a 'grouper' column like this:

```
x['a'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('grouper')
Out: 
   grouper
0        0
0        1
1        1
1        2
```

If you join this with the original DataFrame, it can be grouped as you like:

```
x['a'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('grouper').join(x).groupby('grouper').mean()
Out: 
           b
grouper     
0        1.0
1        1.5
2        2.0
```

Reshaping part is not very efficient but as far as I know pandas does not offer a better method for that yet.